# .NET Core, change databse settings

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Sorry, I've searching but can't found an answer to this. First time using .NET, I need to change the settings for the database. Currently is using IIS express, now I have to use a remote sql server. The `launchSettings.json` settings is this.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:42793",
      "sslPort": 44355
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "factoringxs_autox": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5011;http://localhost:5010"
    }
  }
}
```

So, I have the credentials (IP db, db name, user and password) for the sql server. How can I configure it in `launchSettings.json`?

Comment: The database connection string by default will be in the appSettings.json

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I don't see any var for db port, db name, user, pass, etc, I don't know how to add those credentials there. Currently the app is trying to connect to a local IIS database, but I need to change that in order to conect to the external db of the credentials

Comment: Thanks mate! I search on the entire project, I found the filename `appsettings.Development.json" there are some `"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=XXX;Password=XXX;User=sa",`  thanks you